# usage of regex pattern in grep with multiple subexpressions

Tags: r, regex

There are lot of reading about regex, and I have glossed over some and put much time into it, but now I am hoping to get someone to give me advice and direction for further learning regex.

I am using grep to find lines that have motor vehicle reference in any of the columns of my data set `SCC`.  So I use the following command:

```
sapply(SCC, grep, pattern="(vehicle|motor.*vehicle|motor)", 
    ignore.case = TRUE,
    fixed = FALSE)
```

And I get the list of all the row in all the columns that are of possible interest.

Then I used `value=TRUE`argument of grep(), and unlist(unique()), to see what all rows were captured.

Here are some these entries with that command:

```
   unique(unlist(sapply(SCC, grep, pattern="(vehicle|motor.*vehicle|motor)", ignore.case=TRUE, fixed=FALSE, value=TRUE)))
        [1] "Int Comb /Engine Testing /Rocket Engine Testing /Rocket Motor: Solid Propellant"
        [2] "Highway Veh - Gasoline - Light Duty Vehicles (LDGV) - Total: All Road Types"
        [3] "Highway Veh - Gasoline - Light Duty Vehicles (LDGV) - Rural Interstate: Total"
        [4] "Highway Veh - Gasoline - Light Duty Vehicles (LDGV) - Interstate: Rural Time 1"
        [5] "Highway Veh - Gasoline - Light Duty Vehicles (LDGV) - Interstate: Rural Time 2"     
        .
        .
        .
    [329] "Off-highway Gasoline, 4-Stroke /Recreational Equipt /Motorcycles: Off-road"
    [330] "Off-highway Gasoline, 4-Stroke /Recreational Equipt /All Terrain Vehicles"
    [331] "Off-highway Gasoline, 4-Stroke /Recreational Equipt /Specialty Vehicles/Carts"
    [332] "Off-highway LPG /Recreational Equipt /Motorcycles: Off-road"
```

There were total of 411 unique entries what that were targeted by my grep with (vehicle|motor.*vehicle|motor).  I wanted to change this so that line[1] with string 'Rocket Motor' is not included.  So, I use the this pattern="(vehicle|motor.*vehicle|motorcycle)".

I got what I wanted, but I was curious if there is a way to use regex to match only exclusive strings. I read a little about using regex and tried using something like this:

```
pattern = "^(?=.*?vehicle|motor.*vehicle|motor)((?!\brocket motor\b).)*$"
```

I tried to match everything with 'vehicle, motor vehicle, or motor, but not 'rocket motor'. It's not working, and I am getting error. I would like to know more about usage of regex in R, particularly grep and related functions.  How close or how far am I from using a meaningful regex? Is there a limitation to type of regex I can use for R in particular? I know I will be using regex in future and would like to learn a little bit more from all my effort.

Below is the error I got:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  invalid regular expression '^(?=.*vehicle|motor.*vehicle|motor)((?rocket moto).)*$', reason 'Invalid regexp'
```

Comment: @Jota if I'm not mistaken, that goes in the answer box.

Comment: Thanks Jota, now I feel much better that I know that one bit about regex in R.  And I am not getting the invalid regular expression error.  That would be the exact answer I needed for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `?regex` for more on regular expressions in base R.

With regard to the error you got, see the Details section.  The second sentence is:

> Two types of regular expressions are used in R, *extended* regular
>   expressions (the default) and *Perl-like* regular expressions used by
>   perl = TRUE.

Since you are trying to use Perl-like regular expressions, you need to set `perl = TRUE`.

After the Details section, there is an Extended Regular Expressions section followed by a Perl-like Regular Expressions section where you can find more information.

---

For more regular expression options, you can also use look into `stringi` package which uses the ICU library.